# Uiimagepickercontroller in h or m file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller

I wonder does it make any differences? If its declared in our m file, is it allocated again(thus comsuming extra and redundant memory) each time we uses or both ways mean the same thing and so doesnt make any different which file I declared it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference is the scope of the variable. A variable declared in the header file would be available to all methods within the class. A variable declared within a method is only accessible within that method.

As far as memory goes, in general there is no difference between having your variable declared in the header file or in the .m file.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare UIImagePickerController.h in ***.h, whenever you import ***.h in your other classes then UIImagePickerController.h will also get imported there unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

Difference is scope if you use in .h should be present for everyOne if in .m should present for the function and if you declare in .m with @interface() it should be private.

Comment: Please use proper formatting for your answer so readers can get proper look of your answer and understands it

Comment: I just wrote if you a programmer than you have to know the small thing that;s why i di't describe more...